# Restore SQL Server database in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I backup a database with this command

```
<add name="WindingContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Winding;Integrated Security=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

In view model

```
WindingContext _db = new WindingContext();
BackupCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
 {
   string command = @"BACKUP DATABASE Winding
                       TO DISK = '" + FilePath + "'";
   _db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(command).ToList();}
```

and in restore view model.

```
RestoreCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
 {
   var command = "RESTORE DATABASE Winding FROM DISK = '"+FilePath+
            "' WITH REPLACE, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
   _db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(command).ToList();}
```

but I get an error:

> RESTORE cannot process database 'Winding' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

**Update**:

I use this code but get error

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Master;Integrated Security=True;");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@" Restore Database Winding From Disk='" + FilePath + "'", connection);

try
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
}
```

Comment: Try this in your connection string : Initial Catalog=Master

Comment: wrap the command and "USE master;" into one transaction.

Comment: @Jimbot , pls see update. I change costring but get error.

Comment: Maybe, try to take the database offline before you backup and online after you restore. Not sure, but it may disconnect the user who prevent you to backup.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the database you are trying to restore is the default database.
Go to Security > Logins > your login user. Right click and select properties. Update the Default database to master.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different connection strings. One from code, and one from App.Config.

You have to make sure that in both places the database which has to be restored is not mentioned. Otherwise you have an active connection to that database and a restore will be aborted.

```
<add name="WindingContext" 
 connectionString="Data Source=.YOUR-COMPUTER\INSTANCE-OF-DATABASE; Integrated Security=True;" 
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  // REMOVED Catalog=Wind...
```

Just tested with this, and it worked:

```
class Program
{
    private static masterEntities _db;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _db = new masterEntities();

        try
        {
            Backup(@"C:\Temp\Test\Test123.bak");

            Console.Read();

            Restore(@"C:\Temp\Test\Test123.bak");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void Backup(string filePath)
    {
        var command = @"BACKUP DATABASE Test
                   TO DISK = '" + filePath + "'";
        var list = _db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(command).ToList();
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }

    static void Restore(string filePath)
    {
        var command = "RESTORE DATABASE Test FROM DISK = '" + filePath +
                      "' WITH REPLACE, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
       var list = _db.Database.SqlQuery<List<string>>(command).ToList();

        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```